# Who to notify that their browser is not supported in our new website

Tags: html

We are upgrading our website to be responsive and thus using HTML5 throughout. We also take Paypal to make purchases online. Paypal's standards are changing along with other payment processors to TLS 1.2 for their API. Does this mean that only client browsers that support TLS 1.2 will be able to submit payments through us when making purchases on our site? I believe that client to our server connection is independent of our server to paypal connection. I need to notify users of old browsers when they visit our site to upgrade if they use IE8 anyway as HTML5 is not supported. I am trying to figure out if any other browser users need to be notified.

Comment: Just to clarify, do we notify those that are using browsers that don't support HTML5 or also those that don't support TLS 1.2

Comment: Do you use the API server side to communicate with PayPal. Or is it some client side interaction with PayPal. Beside that HTML5 is a live standard, so you won't tell the visitor that the browser does not support HTML5 but you would test if certain features you use are supported by the browser.

Comment: We use the API server side, collect the info and then forward to Paypal for processing. Server and paypal server have TLS 1.2 handshaking. So my thought is that the browsers level of support is not that important. However, we use things like carousels and other HTML features that their browsers like IE 8 won't support.